# Image classification in python always getting same matching score

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am learning image classification with tensorflow. Below is my program . For any test image input i am getting always matching percentage 100%. i.e. my model always predicting 1. One more issue for same image if i am passing again and again it gives sometimes different  labels

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Flatten,Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.utils import np_utils



classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64,64,3 ),activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(128 , kernel_initializer ='uniform' , activation = 'relu')) 
classifier.add(Dense(10 , kernel_initializer ='uniform' , activation = 'relu'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , metrics = ['accuracy']) 


from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/code/train',
        shuffle=True,
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=5,
        class_mode='categorical',
        classes=["shiv", "kart", "nall","surendra","harshi","nag","saura","rajan","manoj","abhimanyu"])

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/code/validation',
        shuffle=True,
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=5,
        class_mode='categorical',
        classes=["shiv", "kart", "nall","surendra","harshi","nag","saura","rajan","manoj","abhimanyu"])

from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

classifier.fit(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=80,
        epochs=12,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=100)


    from keras_preprocessing import image
    files_dir = '/code/test_image_clasification1'
    files = os.listdir(files_dir)
    np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
    for f in files:
        image_path = files_dir + '/' + f
        test_image = image.load_img(image_path,target_size = (64, 64))
        test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
        test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
        result = classifier.predict(test_image)
        #classes = classifier.predict_classes(test_image)
        #print (classes)
        labels = ["shivaji","kartik","nallayan","surendar","harshita","nagendar","saurabh","rajan","manoj","abhimanyu"]
    indx = np.argmax(result)
    #score = np.argmax(np.round(result*100,2))
    #print(np.round(result,2))
    match_percentage=np.max(result)
    match_class=labels[indx]
    
    print("the image " + f + " is matching with "+ match_class + " having matching percentage  " +"{:.2%}".format(match_percentage) )
    #print(list(zip(labels,result)))
     #print(f,labelsindx])
```

Can any one help me if anything wrong in model training . For information, i have 122 image in train set and 48 in validation set.

Comment: In prediction phase, use the same pre-processing steps as in training phase, i.e. divide pixel values by 255 before feeding it to model.

Comment: @today can you tell me how to do ? any other thing need to be changed ?

Comment: Please see the answer of the duplicate question (the link is in the blue banner at the top of your question).

Comment: @today thanks . Now i am getting percentage other than 100 also. But for same image it is giving different class names.with different matching percentage . What could be reason ? Any mistake is there during training of model.any parameters to be changed ?

Comment: If it's a classification task, then you should not use `relu` as the activation function of last layer; instead, use `softmax`.

Comment: @today Actually i have used softmax also . but facing same issue. Is there any thing to change like optimizer, epoch, steps_per_epoch etc ..?

Comment: If you changed the activation of last layer to `softmax` and still the prediction probability value **for the same image** is different each time you call `predict` method on it, then I am not sure what may be wrong in your code. You can post a new question with enough details and explaining the exact problem you are facing, and hopefully someone might be able to help you.